# Video Game Win % in SQL

Tags: sql-server

in an attempt to teach myself SQL I have started recording results from my video games (Overwatch specifically) in a spreadsheet and have been playing with SQL Server 2012 with the data recorded.

Right now I have a table called GamesPlayed and am trying to create a query where I return map names, wins, losses and win %.

The games played table looks like;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GamesPlayed](
    [GameID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MapName] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [FirstHero] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SecondHero] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Result] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SRChange] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TeamScore] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OppScore] [int] NOT NULL;
```

The Query I was attempting was;

```
SELECT MapName as Map,
    Count(*) as 'Games Played',
    sum(case when Result = 'Win' then 1 else 0 end) Wins,
    sum(case when Result = 'Loss' then 1 else 0 end) Losses,
    Sum(case when Result = 'Win' then 1 else 0 end)/Count(*)*100.00 'Win%'
FROM GamesPlayed
group by MapName
```

The problem I am getting is the Win % column is just returning 0.00 for every row. I think it has something to do with the result column data type. Not sure I need the result column at all either seeing how the win/loss/draw result can be derived from the 2 score columns (TeamScore and OppScore).

Any help getting this to work would be great.

Comment: can you add some data or create sql fiddle?

Comment: If you change the `1` and `0` in the Win % to `1.0` and `0.0`, does that make a difference?

Comment: Zim I accidentally flagged your comment instead of upvoting. my bad!

Comment: Mysql ands sql server are two different products. Pls use only the relevant product tags!

Comment: Thank you Phil, that got it to work. Any insight as to why changing the 1 and 0 in the Win % to 1.0 and 0.0 made it work?

Comment: You could make this a little simpler and change your "Result" column to "PlayerWon" and make it a bit or even a tinyint instead of a varchar.

Comment: The reason changing to 1.0 worked is because of integer math. It will do the division first which would be an int / int so you get an int result, then it multiplies by 100.00 so you will always have two decimal places. Forcing the datatype to a numeric with 1.0 means the division will be on decimals so you can get the correct results.

Comment: why Result is varchar.it should be int win=1,lose=0,draw=2,abaondon=3,tie=4.And in division Count (*) should be cast as decimal(5,2)

Answer (score 1):

Sean Lange provided a great explanation in comments on the question. Simply put you are doing division on integers and will only receive an integer in return. You need to change your datatype on one of the numbers you are dividing with.

```
CREATE TABLE #GamesPlayed(
    [GameID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MapName] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [FirstHero] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SecondHero] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Result] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SRChange] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TeamScore] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OppScore] [int] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #GamesPlayed VALUES
('Map1', 'HeroA', 'HeroB', 'Win', 0, 0, 0),
('Map1', 'HeroA', 'HeroB', 'Loss', 0, 0, 0),
('Map2', 'HeroA', 'HeroB', 'Win', 0, 0, 0),
('Map2', 'HeroA', 'HeroB', 'Win', 0, 0, 0),
('Map3', 'HeroA', 'HeroB', 'Loss', 0, 0, 0)

SELECT
    MapName AS 'Map',
    SUM(1) AS 'Games Played',
    SUM(IIF(Result = 'Win', 1, 0)) AS 'Wins',
    SUM(IIF(Result = 'Loss', 1, 0)) AS 'Losses',
    SUM(IIF(Result = 'Win', 1.0, 0)) / SUM(1) * 100 AS 'Win%'
FROM
    #GamesPlayed
GROUP BY
    MapName

DROP TABLE #GamesPlayed
```

Comment: `SUM(1)` ought to the `SUM(*)`

Comment: Thanks I like this better then using CASE WHEN, would it be better practice to remove the Result column and calculate the wins/losses/draws from the TeamScore and OppScore columns?

Comment: @mallan1121 You can't `SUM(*)`. Did you mean `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @Nate I'll have to give you the classic answer "it depends" on that one. If you want more of an explanation let me know and we can continue the conversation in chat.

Comment: Durr, yes I did. No excuse!

Answer (score 0):

You're query is calculating integers for the percentage. Your options are to cast the wins as a float which will provide the percentage as a float, or you can multiply by 100 before dividing. Try this.

```
SELECT MapName as Map,
    Count(*) as 'Games Played',
    sum(case when Result = 'Win' then 1 else 0 end) Wins,
    sum(case when Result = 'Loss' then 1 else 0 end) Losses,
    Sum((case when Result = 'Win' then 1 else 0 end)*100)/Count(*) 'Win%'
FROM GamesPlayed
group by MapName
```

Edit: Since this is still calculating with integers this will round down. To get decimal precision in your percentage, use floats.

Comment: but you didn't cast anything... nor did you make it a float.

Comment: Nope, I multiplied by 100 before dividing. Assuming you won 5 out of 10 games, 5/10 = .5 (SQL rounds this down to 0) multiplied by 100 = 0. Apposed to 5*100 = 500 / 10 = 50. This avoids decimals, but if you had any it would round down to a whole integer.